# Redirection based on submission for a gateway page PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

So I have one php page that acts a like a gateway to entrance of the actual website based on a users response to question. e.g are you over 18?
But my query is:

-how do I store a users answer to the question?

-how can perhaps a cookie or session variable record whether a user has confirmed or even visited the gateway page?

-how can I ensure that if the "actualpage.php" is cached in the users web browser it doesn't skip the gateway page if they haven't confirmed or visited the page?

Comment: create a session variable that is set to 0 by default. set the variable to 1 once they answer the question. make `actualpage.php` reject anyone with either a 0 for the session variable or if their session variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok great sounds good. But where do I post the code? I'm my gateway page or my actual page or both?

Comment: on the question page check if the session variable exists, if it doesn't then make it equal to 0. When someone answers the question, set that session variable to 1. On the actual page redirect anyone who doesn't have the session variable set to 1.

Comment: If you want anything more specific than I would need code to go off of.

Comment: `<?php 


session_start();


$_SESSION["time"] = 0;




 ?>
`
So this is what I have so far, and I have used the print function determine that it is set to zero. What would be the next step?

Comment: hold on I am going to make an answer explaining everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to set it to 0 by default so i didn't include that below.

**question.php:**

```
session_start();

// if they answered the question
$_SESSION['time'] = 1;
```

**actualpage.php:**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['time'])) {
     header("Location: redirectpage.php");
     exit();
}
// rest of the page code
```

simple as that if you have any other questions then just ask.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Alex One thing I forgot, it's good to use the `exit()` function after redirects otherwise the php code will still run on the page. I updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help!